# How to Add ViewPager Indicator Headings Like Google+ App

Tags: android

My goal is to create a screen similar in function to the Stream page in the Google+ app (picture below for those unfamiliar).  For the paging, I am using a custom `ViewGroup` so that it has smooth transitions that "follow your finger" rather than just snapping to the destination after the fling gesture has been made.

**Question**

Currently, I am going the route of using some `TranslateAnimation`s to move the headings ("Nearby," "All circles," and "Incoming" in the screenshot) once a new page has been selected.  This creates a couple of problems: the center heading doesn't follow the user's finger (as you can see the "All circles" heading does in the screenshot), and if the user begins on a page other than the middle one, I have not found an easy way to offset all of the animations temporarily without running them first since the animations do not move the actual views.

Am I going about this the correct way, or is there a much simpler way of accomplishing this that I am overlooking?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Very good question, tnx!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After hours of searching and a little luck with search terms, I came across [A Google+ like ViewPager page indicator](http://www.zylinc.com/blog-reader/items/viewpager-page-indicator.html).

I also came across [Android ViewPager Indicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), created by the same developer who wrote ActionBarSherlock. Has a ton of examples, and is pretty easy to integrate with the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Good link, thanks, can to get any link where we get the moving tab page indicator for a ViewPager.

Answer (score 5):

Google has published his own solution in support library.

Check:
[PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html), 
[PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html)

Answer (score 3):

Have just used [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) solution and its very nice and smooth. You can demo the effect by looking at the demo from the Android Market [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.viewpagerindicator.sample&feature=search_result)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think it uses the new `ViewPager`.
Maybe you should look at the `API 4+ Support Demos`:

- [FragmentStatePagerSupport.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentStatePagerSupport.html)
- [FragmentPagerSupport.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html)

Comment: They use something similar to the `ViewPager` in the app, but the `ViewPager` itself doesn't provide support for the headings.  I did, however, finally come across a blog post by somebody who recreated it.  Thanks for your input.